# How to get a single object with only the foreign keys using "render json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, foreign-keys, has-many, belongs-to

I'm building a backend using Rails 3.2.8 and I have a huge object graph with lots of dependencies etc.

**Example:**

```
A belongs_to B (and of course B has_many A)
B belongs_to C
C belongs_to D
etc...
```

If I now open the URL "http://0.0.0.0:3000/ds.json", I'll get the whole object graph.

```
[{"id":1,"c":{
    "id":1,"b":{
        "id":1,"a":{
            "id":1
        }
    }
}]
```

(I have a custom database where the foreign keys are with out the "_id" suffix).

Instead I'd like to just get the id of "C" if I open "ds.json":

```
[{"id":1,"c":1}]
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
My Models look like this (and I think that's the problem, but I can't change the database scheme):

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'location'
  self.primary_key = 'id'

  belongs_to :map, foreign_key: :map
end



class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'map'
  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_many :locations, foreign_key: :map
end
```

The problem seems to be that rails just sees "map" inside the "location" and just grabs the whole object, because "map" is the name of the object AND the id-column inside the location-table...

How can I tell Rails the difference between object and id-column ?!

Comment: you're saying 'My Controllers look like this' but you're showing your models :/

Comment: And I suggest you have a look at https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers or at https://github.com/nesquena/rabl but I really prefer serializers :)

Comment: yeah sorry. it' already pretty late here ;-) Isn't there any simple solution? I have now renamed my Models by appending an "a" to all of their class- and file-names. This works, 'cause now Rails sees that model and table-column are different. But there must be a better way without renaming my files als classes...

Comment: waw this definitely sounds like an ugly workaround, I really think that using active model serializers, you can find a way to properly serialize your objects

Comment: Another workaround is: instead of `belongs_to :map, foreign_key: :map`, I can write: `belongs_to :mapasdf, foreign_key: :map, class_name: 'Map'`. But now I have to remember all the time that I have to use `Location.mapasdf` instead of `Location.map`... I'm still not satisfied **EDIT:** This causes a bug: If I now write `Location.map = someMapObject` it inserts always `1` as map-id.